# What are the methods of rolling out new/beta features to a large user-base?

Tags: deployment

So as to avoid overwhelming the infrastructure in a web application instance, what would be the methods of implementing a feature roll out to a controlled group of your user-base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation. You can't really redirect them to another site using another database if the users are expecting to work with real data and the real site.

I would introduce a flag on your users in your user-table, let's say isBetaUser (bool). Then you can just show these new features for users that got this flag set to True. You could also let them check this flag off using a checkbox through some settings page, if they don't like the idea of trying out new features that is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Partition your users into groups.  Randomly.  Demographically.  Somehow.
2. Pick one or more groups for a pilot.
3. Fix your web site to have both versions of your app running.  Maybe use virtual hosting or a different path or something.

   One database.  Two applications.  Data doesn't move.  Only the presentation changes.

   At first, all users are in the old version.  Workload has not changed.
4. Move a group of users so that their default URL's or links or menus or whatever are references to the new application.

   Same workload.  Same database.  Same number of users.  Two applications.
5. Move another group of users to the new application.

   Same workload.  Same database.  Same number of users.  Two applications.
6. Eventually, after all users are moved, you can delete the old application.

Comment: How would that work if you have database structure changes? You would not be able to use the same database.

Comment: @joerage: You have to have both sets of data in one database.  That means that you move the data from old structure to new structure as part of moving users.  Any shared data has to be bridged between the two structures.  Incrementally moving users isn't necessary and causes problems rather than solving them.  Moving everyone at once is simpler and doesn't "overwhelm the infrastructure."

Comment: This should work well theoretically, but I don't know if any company uses this method in a real world project

Comment: @Swizzh:  I guess we're not real world.